# How to remove title bar from terminal on the new Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: command-line, 20.04

I used this method in 18.04 (https://joshtronic.com/2017/07/26/hide-title-bars-in-gnome-shell/) but it doesn't working now... Any ideas?

P.S. I used a standard desktop environment

P.P.S. To be more precise: I used to have a clean terminal without ANY bars, status bars, borders etc. in any window size and I am trying to achieve this again in new ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: [Unite](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/) works great if you want to merge window title with the header bar.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What finally worked for me was to run:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-pixelsaver
gnome-extensions enable pixel-saver@deadalnix.me
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings headerbar false
```

in the terminal, then restart the shell (Alt-F2, r).

Comment: Thanks, that's a solution! And so simple this time.

Comment: I got `E: Package 'gnome-shell-extension-pixelsaver' has no installation candidate` on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

Comment: On 22.04, you need to install `gnome-shell-extension-manager` and then install the Pixelsaver extension through that.

Answer (score 10):

Very simple!

1. Install **dconf-editor**

   for ubuntu-like distros
   `sudo apt install dconf-editor`

   for arch distros
   `pacman -S dconf-editor`
2. Open **dconf-editor**
3. Go to `/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/headerbar`
4. Disable "**Default value**" and change "**Custom value**" to "**False**".
5. Close *all* your `gnome-terminal` windows and then reopen your terminal. Voilà!

To remove menu bar, in terminal go to **"View"** and uncheck **"Show menu bar"** (or something else).

**[Edit]**

**OR**
Just open your terminal, copy and paste code below:
`gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings headerbar "@mb false"`

If didn't work, install `dconf-cli` and try again.

To remove menu bar in terminal, go to **"View"**, and uncheck **"Show menu bar"** (or something else).

Comment: This not appear to work in ubuntu 22

Comment: The second suggestion, `gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings headerbar "@mb false"`, worked lovely in Debian bookworm.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is still a relevant question, but other answers do not work on Ubuntu 22+ or delete all titlebars instead of only the terminal one, I thought that an update might be nice.
I tried to write something that works out-of-the-box and shared the snippet on github in this [repo](https://github.com/safesintesi/terminal-guillotine) :)

This is tested to work on Ubuntu 23.10 and removes ONLY the terminal titlebar/headerbar.

You can just copy the css or use the script in the repo if you're lazy :)

Comment: Copying over the CSS applied immediately after restarting the Gnome terminal on Fedora 39.

Answer (score 0):

I use Unite and it works for me.

To install **Unite** you need to open up Firefox and install an add on. Just visit Firefox addons page for to install [gnome shell integration](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnome-shell-integration/). Once ready, click + Add to Firefox

After that, in terminal enter this code:

```
sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell
```

Finally, visit [Unite extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/) page and slide the button up right from off to on. The extension will be installed. You can refresh the page to click on the configurations button of the extensions on the same page.

Comment: This extension does nothing to terminal at all.

Comment: Same here. Unite does a lot of useful things, but the window titlebar stays where it is for all GTK3 apps. Works for Firefox etc., but not for Terminal, GEdit etc.

Comment: It works great for me, thanks !
Took me a while to realize it is installed and controlled via FIREFOX ONLY.

Comment: Unite only can remove decorations on Xorg. Ubuntu 21.04 puts you on Wayland, even after an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on this site: https://joshtronic.com/2017/07/26/hide-title-bars-in-gnome-shell/

[Copy this code from site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5g1x.png) and paste in ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css (open this with gedit or nano (I used gedit)).

After that save and you can close that windows (gedit) *and I prefer you open new terminal*. After you done that part, in shell (terminal) paste this code:
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings headerbar "@mb false"

(this command is on that site too), after that do ALT + F2 and put latter "r" in command line, click ENTER. This fixed my problem.
You just need to open new terminal and see if that worked.

*^* If this doesnt work than open terminal and paste those commands:
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-pixelsaver
gnome-extensions enable pixel-saver@deadalnix.me
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings headerbar false

and after that go to ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css if code you paste that disapear copy it and paste it again. Again, run command line:
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings headerbar "@mb false"

And after that do ALT+F2 and in command line put latter r and click ENTER.
You just need to open new terminal and see if that worked.

I hope this helped some. Nice day to all of you guys! :)

Answer by:
-epeu

I had the same problem and asked for help today and somehow find some solution: (link to my question and solution)
https://askubuntu.com/a/1387051/1561747