# I want to remove this terminal bar, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, 20.04

I am Using Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 and would like to remove the top bar that sits above the Terminal window:

[image: Ubuntu Terminal]

I tried to remove "Terminal bar" through settings, but didn't see anything that would allow it. I checked for Gnome Extensions, but there doesn't seem to be one that does what I want. I've also searched on websites and YouTube videos for a solution and found none.

How can I hide *just* the top bar on Terminal?

This bar:

[image: Terminal Bar]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1231559/1222991) might be the one you're looking for 

Comment: Thanks on your help, my friend. I already saw that and tried, but that didin't work...

Comment: Sir, when I maximized terminal, I don't see my bar anymore, but when is on 80x24 or some other resolution bar's there again... Is this some technical issue, or...?

Comment: @matigo I tried something with code on that site (site you can find on that link you posted for me), and improvized something with that and that fixed my problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on this site: https://joshtronic.com/2017/07/26/hide-title-bars-in-gnome-shell/

[Copy this code from site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5g1x.png) and paste in ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css (open this with gedit or nano (I used gedit)).

After that save and you can close that windows (gedit) *and I prefer you open new terminal*. After you done that part, in shell (terminal) paste this code:
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings headerbar "@mb false"

(this command is on that site too), after that do ALT + F2 and put latter "r" in command line, click ENTER. This fixed my problem.
You just need to open new terminal and see if that worked.

**^** If this doesnt work than open terminal and paste those commands:
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-pixelsaver
gnome-extensions enable pixel-saver@deadalnix.me
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings headerbar false

-and after that go to ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css if code you paste that disapear copy it and paste it again. Again, run command line:
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings headerbar "@mb false"

And after that do ALT+F2 and in command line put latter r and click ENTER.
You just need to open new terminal and see if that worked.

I hope this helped some. Nice day to all of you guys! :)

Answer by:
-epeu

Comment: What "mb false" does compared to just "false"?