# How to hide/remove GNOME terminal title bar?

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell-extension

How can I hide the GNOME terminal titlebar?

I have tried extensions like "unite" and it does not always hide the titlebar. It is only hidden when maximized.

[image: cropped screenshot of title bar in GNOME terminal]

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Comment: This is a duplicate. It has already been solved in https://askubuntu.com/q/1230157/1652872

Comment: None of those solutions work. Unite, dconf, gnome-shell-extension-pixelsaver, the custom css. Could ubuntu gnome have changed since that initial question

Comment: @Alejandro: No duplicate. We are talking about Gnome 4.3 which is more deteriorated than Gnome 3.x was

Answer (score 1):

The gnome-terminal has a csd titlebar which looks different in 22.04 than your screenshot - so what did you do to it?

But you can remove your csd altogether: either for your terminal or all of your windows. I will not question the reason, because you'll strip yourself from moving, minimizing etc your window - but thats your choice.

**Brute force:**

create the file `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` and define it:

```
.titlebar, .css, headerbar{
  background-image:none;
  background-color:transparent;
  margin-top:-100px;
  margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

Now you don't have any csd on any window...

**Single window only:**

Gnome might let you - if you tweak your own full blownup theme. Nmath described Gnome very well :-)

```
GNOME_THEME=zerohead gnome-terminal
```

or

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme zerohead
```

where "zerohead" is the name of the tweaked theme. (The latter changes most of the other apps as well)

From my point of view it is possible to tweak this stuff, but Gnome is certainly the worst environment for doing this. (XFCE or KDE would be a better choice)

Comment: That css does work to hide it, but like you mntioned it does it to all windows. I'm not quite sure what you are suggesting to do to only target the terminal window. I use Graphite-Dark theme

Comment: As a matter of fact I tried to use the GNOME_THEME env for single app (still works in Ubuntu 20.04) - but Gnome 43  obviously doesn't use it any more.  With XFCE it works (which doesn't help you). I'm still investigating how to circumvent those constraints.

Comment: ok ye there seems to be alot of customisation solutions out there that no longer work. I was also lookng at trying to add padding to the terminal, but a lot of those answers don't work anymore.

Comment: gnome-terminal and gnome-calculator are "Gnome territory" which use libadwaita - another step towards crippling themes. I wrote about Gnome in [my theme](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1424967/)